# My flutter_bloc demo doesn't work. The Scaffold's body seems all grayed out. What do I miss here?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

I try to run demo in this page
https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterbloccoreconcepts?id=counter_blocdart

It's supposed to display Center container and its subtree but here is what I got.

[image: Screenshot]

This is my `main.dart`.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'dart:async';

enum CounterEvent { increment, decrement }

class CounterBloc extends Bloc<CounterEvent, int> {
  CounterBloc() : super(0);

  @override
  Stream<int> mapEventToState(CounterEvent event) async* {
    switch (event) {
      case CounterEvent.decrement:
        yield state - 1;
        break;
      case CounterEvent.increment:
        yield state + 1;
        break;
    }
  }
}

class CounterPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Counter')),
      body: BlocBuilder<CounterBloc, int>(
        builder: (context, count) {
          return Center(
            child: Text(
              '$count',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0),
            child: FloatingActionButton(
              child: Icon(Icons.add),
              onPressed: () {
                context.read<CounterBloc>().add(CounterEvent.increment);
              },
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0),
            child: FloatingActionButton(
              child: Icon(Icons.remove),
              onPressed: () {
                context.read<CounterBloc>().add(CounterEvent.decrement);
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: CounterPage()
    );
  }
}
```

What do I miss out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are not providing the CounterBloc in the tree. Provide the Bloc using BlocProvider:

Wrap the CounterPage in a BlocProvider like that:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      // Added BlocProvider
      home: BlocProvider( 
        create: (context) => CounterBloc(),
        child: CounterPage(),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

This way you can access your CounterBloc in the child widgets of the BlocProvider. If you want to provide multiple BLoCs you can use MultiBlocProvider

Comment: Thank you. Does the corresponding `BlocProvider` object have to be rooted at the top most widget in the tree or can be at just one level above its `BlocBuilder`?